# How to create multiple Refs dynamically in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-ref

I have multiple Swipeable components in my React Native app, that are being created dynamically by users, in order for the Swipeable to close on its own, I've set a reference to it, and called a close function on it, however, this only works for the last created Swipeable, and not for all of them, how can I make the ref apply for all of them?

here's my code:

```js
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
const Swipeablee = useRef();

     return(
 {messages.map(({id, data}) => (
 <Swipeable key={id} renderLeftActions={leftActions}
                onSwipeableLeftOpen={() => swipeAction(data)}
                overshootLeft={false}
                ref={Swipeablee}
                overshootFriction={8} >
)}
)
```

and here's the function I'm calling:

```js
const swipeAction = (data) => {

        Swipeablee.current.close()
  }
```

Comment: You need to share some more code. How do you store Swipeables, what is `id`? When you insert new Swipeable, you can also create a ref and store it the same way

Comment: @Sohaib thanks for commenting, I've edited the code, as you can see, I'm mapping through an array of messages and each one returns a Swipeable that has its own id from firebase.

Comment: Still unclear on how you call `setMessages`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do this. Create an array with `useRef` and store the ref in it  once `Swipeable` component renders.

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
const refs = useRef([]); // using useRef because we want to persist the values when component re-renders

const swipeAction = (data, swipeable) => {
  // process data
  swipeable.close()
}


return(
   {messages.map(({id, data}, index) => (
      <Swipeable key={id} renderLeftActions={leftActions}
            onSwipeableLeftOpen={() => swipeAction(data, refs.current[index])}
            overshootLeft={false}

            // Store the Swipeable to our array, ref prop will give us the component once it is rendered
            ref={swipeable => refs.current[index] = swipeable}

            overshootFriction={8} />
    )}
)
```

Comment: But where does index come from? Do i have to assign it?

Comment: index comes from `map` function. you don't have to assign it